# How to deal with project owner who sees complexity of project by UI

Tags: work-environment

I work in a small team of less then 50 people, I am working with same company for around 6 years. Recently I started working on a ground breaking project.

The part of project I am developing has only 2 UI pages whereas rest of 3 developers have little more then mine.

Here are issues I am facing,

- Project owner who is also owner of the company undermines my project which is a lot dynamic - requires lots of coding algorithm and less UI.
- I achieved 50% of requirements but when it was showed to one of proposed end client, PO changed it's requirement which was so crucial that I had to rewrite the project. Blame goes on me for not choosing right technology at first place. This technology I am using was in no way going to deliver what was initially required **easily**
- Other developers in team are enjoying rush free environment and am being pushed hard because of rewriting project from scratch which was not my fault (my manager understand that too - and I have everything in emails)

Now my manager is with me, but I am not sure how to communicate this issue in such a manner that I won't get blamed for being slow as appraisals are near.. and this could badly effect it, even though I always had an impression of hardworker and ***one of most productive person in team in eyes of my manager***.

Apart from above, my manager and some team members know my best abilities but PO doesn't knows much about me, so I am finding lack of trust in the way I communicate if compared to other developers

Comment: The other thing you can do demo scrum style at the end of specified periods ( say 2 weeks ). This gives you feedback as to what people/clients are expecting instead of waiting for 3 months and then rewriting the whole thing.

Comment: By manager do you mean the project manager or your functional/unit manager?  Is the process owner also managing the project?  Is there a business analyst involved?

Answer (score 5):

Your manager will/should have the biggest input into your appraisal. That's part of his/her role. The PO on the other hand is not there to see the day to day work.

So realistically it's your manager you really need to impress, and it's your manager who should be backing you up in terms of explaining things to the PO. There's not a great deal else you can do.

Part of your managers role is to act as a buffer between his/her team and the rest of the World, you shouldn't be explaining yourself directly to the PO without keeping your manager in the loop (if at all). One of the main reasons for this is to cover your back in these sorts of situations.

Comment: +1 - You have to work with your manager first and how she is in alignment with the rest of the company and will stick up for you.